# Table view clear dont clear the view

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I have a table view defined like following

```
@FXML
private TableView<ModelFieldTableEntry> modelFieldsTable;
```

When the user click i reload the table with the clicked item details. Before i reload i call clear on table items

```
modelFieldsTable.getItems().clear();
```

But I see strange behaviour because suppose i clicked a item and it has 4 rows
[image]

Now when i click on another item and i try to reload the table it looks like following. This is very strange because there should be only 1 row but the size of the rows are same like from previous click and the rest of the rows are empty besides the icons. When i click the icons nothing happens. Anybody faced such situation before. Anybody knows what might be causing this ?

My tools def looks like following. They are just 2 `TableColumn`'s

```
 fieldEditColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().editToolProperty());
 fieldEditColumn.setCellFactory(p -> new ColumnEditCell(......));
 fieldDeleteColumn.setCellFactory(p -> new ColumnDeleteCell(.....));
 fieldDeleteColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().deleteProperty());

public class ColumnEditCell extends TableCell<ModelFieldTableEntry, Boolean> {

    private Button cellButton;

    public ColumnEditCell(....) {
        .....
        initializeHandleEvent();
    }

    private void initializeHandleEvent() {
        cellButton = new Button();
        cellButton.setGraphic(IconUtils.createIcon(FontAwesomeIcon.EDIT));

        cellButton.setOnAction(t -> {
            .....
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(final Boolean t, final boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(t, empty);
        if (!empty) {
            setItem(t);
            setGraphic(cellButton);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "undo" changes in case a cell becomes empty. You have not done this which results in cells that were filled but become empty later to remain unchanged. In this case you need to apply the following change to `ColumnEditCell.updateItem`:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(final Boolean t, final boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(t, empty);
    if (empty) {
        setGraphic(null); // remove graphic
    } else {
        // setItem(t); //already done by super.updateItem
        setGraphic(cellButton);
    }
}
```